# Is it possible to replace .find() query with variable in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, syntax

**Problem:**

I am no expert in javascript / meteor syntax

**What I want to achieve:**

replace queries inside .find() with variable to make the code simpler

**My Code:**

Um.. this code basically searches through collections. It will find installed items Or installed items with certain name.

```
Template.xxx.helpers({
  case_a: () => {
    if(A === true){
      var case1 = case_1.find({ isInstalled: true }).fetch();
      var case2 = case_2.find({ isInstalled: true }).fetch();            
    } else {
      var case1 = case_1.find({ "name": {$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*"), $options: 'i'}, isInstalled: true }).fetch();
      var case2 = case_2.find({ "name": {$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*"), $options: 'i'}, isInstalled: true }).fetch();
    }
    var ret = case1.concat(case2);
    return ret;
  }
});
```

**What I would like to know:**

proper syntax that assigned into query

```
Template.xxx.helpers({
  case_a: () => {
    var query = {};
    if(A === true){
      query = { isInstalled: true };      
    } else {
      query = { "name": {$regex: (".*"+searchText+".*"), $options: 'i'}, isInstalled: true };
    }
    var case1 = case_1.find({ query }).fetch();
    var case2 = case_2.find({ query }).fetch();            
    var ret = case1.concat(case2);
    return ret;
  }
});
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `query` is a object, it can be passed directly to the `find()` method.

```
case_1.find(query)
```

instead of

```
case_1.find({query})
```